# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gunicorn'

Tags: django, gunicorn

I followed a [DigitalOcean guide]((https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-debian-10) to set up my Django site. It usually works fine but lately I keep running into this.

```
root@localhost:/usr/bin# sudo systemctl status gunicorn
Jun 13 21:27:43 localhost systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Jun 13 21:27:43 localhost gunicorn[20611]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jun 13 21:27:43 localhost gunicorn[20611]:   File "/usr/bin/gunicorn", line 6, in <module>
Jun 13 21:27:43 localhost gunicorn[20611]:     from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
Jun 13 21:27:43 localhost gunicorn[20611]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gunicorn'
Jun 13 21:27:43 localhost systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 13 21:27:43 localhost systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 13 21:27:43 localhost systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 13 21:27:43 localhost systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 13 21:27:43 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.
```

```
root@localhost:/home/development/django# which gunicorn
/usr/bin/gunicorn
```

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/development/django/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          app.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Did you install gunicorn package?

Comment: Yeah I pip installed it with the other packages.Thats why I added the "which gunicorn" capture here. Says its installed in /usr/bin/gunicorn

Comment: @user3790375 Did you fix the error? I have the same error but with another package. I've installed it and all the other packages but still have the same error.

Comment: No, unfortunately I never did.

Comment: Well, try checking if the user you are using has permissions to access those directories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and was going quite mad but here is what fixed it :

I guess systemd executes with sudo, but I did the `pip install blabla` without being in sudo.
Found out by doing `sudo gunicorn --version` and getting nothing.

So just doing `sudo pip install gunicorn` solved it for me !

Disclaimer : I am probably doing something not at all in the "best practices" so don't hesitate to correct me or give a more detailed response than mine : First time answering :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I wonder if you weren't in a virtualenv. I tried what you did, while in a virtualenv, and it didn't install within the directory for that env